# Multiple Images from separate input fields with php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

How to insert and update multiple images from multiple input fields in one form with PHP Ajax.

For example:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="img1">
    <input type="file" name="img2">
    <input type="file" name="img3">

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your input name into an array.

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="img[]">
    <input type="file" name="img[]">
    <input type="file" name="img[]">

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: I have separate columns for them in my table, and I don`t want to insert them all in one column

Comment: Your comment here suggests this is more a problem with the SQL query than sending files via AJAX - is that correct?

Comment: But how to solve it? I can insert them successfully but could not  update them